# How to connect Docker from another host?

Tags: docker

I tried the below:

```
sudo docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d &
```

But I got :

```
flag provided but not defined: -d
```

I am using docker 1.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found -d is deprecated now. Instead of that `dockerd` is used.

```
sudo dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
```

[Official Documentation Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket)

Comment: I think `docker daemon` is also deprecated, it's `dockerd`.